# How do I move my pygame Image while the rest is happening in background?

Tags: python, pygame

How do I make this zombie PNG move by itself? Currently it only moves when I move my mouse or press any key (trigger an event). I have tried threading too but it seems to freeze my window. I'm trying to make the zombie move while also making pygame respond to my code and input and not freeze the screen/ create lag I'm also fairly new to pygame but experienced in basic python

Code:

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame as pg
from time import sleep as sp
from threading import Thread
import random as rnd

# init pygame

pg.init()

# initialize the window

sInfo = pg.display.Info()
height = 1800
width = 1080

screen = pg.display.set_mode((0,0),pg.FULLSCREEN)
pg.display.set_caption("Gunman Game")
running = True
alive = True

# variabes

shot = False
loaded = False
enem_spawn = True
can_fill = True
enem_max = 5
ch_y = 300
ch_x = 0
enem_y = 300
enem_x = 2000

# load resources

loading_screen = pg.image.load("resources\\loading_screen.png").convert()
background = pg.image.load("resources\\background.png").convert()
ch_idle = pg.image.load("resources\\soldier_idle.png").convert()
ch_shoot = pg.image.load("resources\\soldier_shoot.png").convert()
zombie_idle = pg.image.load("resources\\zombie_idle.png").convert()
win = pg.image.load("resources\\win.png").convert()
lose = pg.image.load("resources\\lose.png").convert()

# constant pygame loop


while running:

  for event in pg.event.get():

    if event.type == pg.QUIT:
      running = False


    # movement system and shooting


    if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pg.K_f:
        shot = True
        if enem_x in range(0,600):
          enem_spawn = False
          alive = False
          screen.blit(win,(0,0))
          



    elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
      shot = False
      pass

    # blit images
    if alive == True:
      if shot == False:
        screen.blit(ch_idle,(ch_x,ch_y))
      elif shot:
        screen.blit(ch_shoot,(ch_x,ch_y))

    if enem_spawn != False:
      if alive != False:
     
        screen.blit(zombie_idle,(enem_x,enem_y))
        enem_x -= 15

    pg.display.update()


    # lose statement

    if enem_x <= ch_x:
      alive = False
      screen.blit(lose,(0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason threading is freezing your screen is because python suffers from global interpreter lock, the interpreter can only do one thing at a time.

The event loop is a nice idea. Just have your game trigger events. For example, you could make your zombie trigger a 'think' event which decides what action it will take and then takes that action as well as push another 'think' event to the back of the event queue.

The issue with this approach is scalability (you won't be able to get massive hordes of zombies and a responsive game). However, it should be good enough to make decent progress without forcing you to switch language.

Comment: first of threading is kinda meant to run multiple processes at the same time, so that shouldn't freeze anything (maybe could try multiprocessing), second scalability can be improved with using classes and `Sprite` class provided by `pygame` (issues in performance would arise only if a lot was done every iteration (like a lot of mathematical stuff in python (which can be improved using `numba` library), otherwise I may have underestimated what you meant by "hordes" (maybe missed the "number" by a few thousand)), it is possible to create pretty decent games (even 3D) using only python)